# How to disable date parsing in Import?

Tags: import

I am trying to import a `.csv` file which has columns of strings, reals and dates. Import keeps giving me the dates as `DateObject`, which make it difficult to export later on. How can I disable that feature when importing?

Comment: Welcome to *Mathematica*.SE! Could you please share the code you use to import and few lines of a `.csv` file in the same format as have?

Comment: Also, please tell us how you want to represent dates in Mathematica if not as `DateObject`

Comment: Take a look at ReadList and friends.

Comment: [Please show a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): a sample CSV files (2-3 lines are enough), and the precise `Import` command you were using. I cannot reproduce what you claim and the documentation seems to state that `Import` does not interpret dates by default. That has to be requested explicitly through the `"DateStringFormat"` option.

Comment: Yeah, an example CSV file would be great.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick replies! Below is an example of the table I imported. simply using `Import[foo.csv]`. If you do so you will notice the dates automatically get formatted as `DateObjects`, I would rather them be kept as strings (to be easily exported later on)\  a b c d e f g
foo this that 4/21/2018 foo this that
this that  foo 5/22/2019 this that foo

Answer (score 2):

If `data` contains an array of what you have imported, then you can convert all `DateObject`s into strings by `data /. a_DateObject :> DateString[a]`.